# How to convert an FAA Sectional GeoTIFF maps into slippy map tiles

Tags: geotiff-tiff, tiles, slippy

The FAA publishes aeronautical maps for the US in a GeoTIFF format: https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/.

I would like to convert the GeoTIFF into a tile set (in my case, I'd like to use it with the Qt Location offline plugin, which uses the Slippy format).

I am looking for a full soup-to-nuts approach, preferably with `gdal`.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but may help other, did you try https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html

e.g.

```
python3 gdal2tiles.py  NewYork/New\ York\ SEC.jpeg  -p raster test2
```